# Составить запрос для таблиц со связью many-to-one

Tags: hibernate, java, mysql

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, с запросом.
Есть таблица `Orders` и `Locations`, между ними связь `many-to-one`. Нужно выбрать все записи из таблицы `Orders`, где `Order.locations.export == null`
При этом использовать критерии не обязательно. Важен результат, любым методом `hibernate`. Спасибо заранее

Comment: Связь many-to-one в какую сторону?

Comment: order many-to-on location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("from Orders o inner join o.locations l where l.export is null");
```

Типа того